Fixing a loose window stool and apron
First-time homeowner here.
We noticed the window stool and apron on our bedroom window is loose. What's the proper way to fix/reinforce it?
And what kind of sealant or caulking do we need to seal it back up?
I couldn't find any videos or advice on fixing it, only full replacements (which were hoping to avoid)
Thanks in advance!

what is causing them to be loose?

nails to secure, wood fill where no change in plane, caulk where change in plane.  pictures need for better answer.
